# 10k user view of pending deletes clogged with invisible 20k votes

Tags: discussion, bug, 10k-tools

Example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5217635/advice-me-to-create-a-tv-programme-schedule-listing-app-closed

Are all these really examples of the OP deleting and then undeleting? There seem to be a lot of them.

Based on comments, I conclude that what is happening is this: the 20k users are cheerfully voting to delete things. These things are counted as 'most delete votes' even for 10k users, so they appear to have no delete votes at all. This diminishes the utility of the delete tab for 10k users, since the things we can act on are not shown if the few slots are occupied by things we can't on.

Comment: It does have a delete vote. Is it yours?

Comment: I don't see any delete votes either. Can we not see them because we are only in the 10k privileges range and the question is less than 48 hours old?

Comment: Maybe, but in that case who could have cast a non-binding vote?

Comment: @mmyers [20k users](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/trusted-user) don't need to wait two days

Comment: Ah. I thought that only applied to negatively voted questions.

Comment: @mich and 20k users's votes are invisible to non-20-k users?

Comment: Does this still happen?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be an issue anymore? Or at least I don't see anything special about this example question and I haven't noticed any particular oddities with other recently deleted questions. Holler if I missed something here.

Comment: I wouldn't know since I have 20k :-)